# Nesting View components inside Text components not working react-native 0.60-RC

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native v0.60.0 RC 0 and on the github release it says the following:

"Enable views to be nested within Text component"

The above does not work for me. The text inside the nested View is not showing up.

My code:

```
    <Text>
        <View>
            <Text>Hello world!</Text>
        </View>
    </Text>
```

This doesn't show anything on screen.

Comment: My assumption is that you can nest Views inside of a Text to achieve other things, such as rendering an icon, bullet points, etc... I guess that nested Text still needs to be a direct child of the Text element.

E.g.: you can now write something like this: ```<Text><View style={{ width: 10, height: 10, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /></Text>```

Comment: you need to wrap another <View> tag around the outer <Text> component.

Comment: Sadly that does not work.

`<View><Text><View><Text>Hello world!</Text></View></Text></View>`